# Activity buttons do not trigger onClick function after network connectivity is disabled

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-activity

I am writing an application which sends HTTP requests to a server if the network is available or queues them up if the network is not available. I am facing an issue with buttons on the activity not working after disabling the network (via `F8` or Airplane mode). Before the network is disabled the buttons correctly trigger their onClick functions, after disabling the network the buttons simply do not trigger their onClick functions.

Below is the code I'm using. It's a very trivial application at the moment (all stub code generated by Eclipse) and I just cannot work out what is causing this issue. Has anyone come across any issues like this before? Thanks for any advice.

*Running this code in an Android 4.0.1 AVD on the Emulator.*

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >   

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="Send Request"
    android:onClick="SendRequestOnClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void SendRequestOnClick(View v)
    {
        Log.i(getPackageName(), "Button 1 Clicked!");

    }     
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this on any device ?

Comment: I hadn't up until now, thanks for the suggestion. Just tried it now and it seems to be a problem in the emulator. Works fine on my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the code on a device (after @anDroider suggested it. Thanks!) it turns out that the above code works fine, as expected. It appears to be a bug or limitation in the emulator. I've also noticed problems with network connectivity related broadcast receivers not being triggered on the emulator, which may or may not be related (just noting it here in case someone stumbles across a problem like this).

Answer (score 0):

try this in your Java class

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i(getPackageName(), "Button 1 Clicked!");
        }
    });
```

and remove this line from `XML` file `android:onClick="SendRequestOnClick"`